# ML.NET cant load TensorFlow Model h5

Tags: tensorflow, ml.net

Hi can't load TensorFlow Model help me please.
Model url : https://nomeroff.net.ua/models/ocr/ua/anpr_ocr_ua_17-cpu.h5
Code:

```
            string patch = basedirectory+ "\\anpr_ocr_ua_17-cpu.h5";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(patch))
        {

            MLContext mLContext = new MLContext(seed: 1);
            TensorFlowModel tensorFlowModel = mLContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(patch);
            //DataViewSchema schema1;
            //var model = mLContext.Model.Load(patch, out schema1);
            var scheme = tensorFlowModel.GetInputSchema();
            DataViewSchema schema = tensorFlowModel.GetModelSchema();
            Console.WriteLine(" =============== TensorFlow Model Schema =============== ");
            var featuresType = (VectorDataViewType)schema["Features"].Type;
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: Features, Type: {featuresType.ItemType.RawType}, Size: ({featuresType.Dimensions[0]})");
            var predictionType = (VectorDataViewType)schema["Prediction/Softmax"].Type;
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: Prediction/Softmax, Type: {predictionType.ItemType.RawType}, Size: ({predictionType.Dimensions[0]})");
            var modelYTesflow = tensorFlowModel.GetModelSchema();
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to load?

Comment: ValueError: No model found in config file.
File url: https://nomeroff.net.ua/models/options/0.3.x/numberplate_options_2019_10_07.h5